# How to know if next getline is EOF C++

Tags: c++

Hi i'm doing some project to read input from csv file, the value i extract from file are Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute, Windspeed, SolarRadiation.

```
bool readFile(MasterMap &mastMap){

const string index = "MetData/data.txt"; //<--- container of every file name constant cant change
string temp, temp2, token;           // <--temp to store filename from index,
                                     // <-- temp2 to getline from every single line from file
                                     // << token to store temporary data

ifstream myFile(index.c_str()); // create ifstream to read into the index file
    if(myFile.is_open()){
        while(getline(myFile, temp))
        {
            cout << temp << endl; // <--- Print out the file name (testing)

            string fileName = "MetData/"+temp; // <-- filename is to contain temp
            ifstream actualFile(fileName.c_str()); // <--- Open the File

            if(actualFile.is_open())
            {
                time timeValue;
                MonthsMap monthMap;
                windLog wLog;
                solarRadiation SR;
                windSpeed WS;

                string MonthYear = "";
                int MY = 0;
                int day = 0;
                int totalCount = 0;
                getline(actualFile, temp2); //remove the first line of the file.
                while(**actualFile.eof()**)
                {
                    getline(actualFile, temp2)
                    stringstream ss(temp2); // <-- pas line to stream

                    getline(ss, token,'/'); // <--Token for day;
                    int dayTemp = atoi(token.c_str());

                    getline(ss, token,'/'); // <--Token for month;
                    string month = token.c_str();

                    getline(ss, token,' '); // <--Token for year;
                    string year = token.c_str();
                    MonthYear = month + year;




                    if(MY == 0 && day == 0){
                        MY = atoi(MonthYear.c_str());
                        day = dayTemp;
                    }





                    if(day!=dayTemp || actualFile.eof()){
                        monthMap.insertWindLog(day, wLog);
                        wLog = windLog();
                        day = dayTemp;
                            if(MY!=atoi(MonthYear.c_str()) || actualFile.eof()){
                                    cout << "Entered Month > " << MY << endl;
                                mastMap.insertData(MY, monthMap);
                                monthMap = MonthsMap();
                                MY=atoi(MonthYear.c_str());
                            }

                            getline(ss, token,':'); // <-- Token for Hour;
                                timeValue.setHour(atoi(token.c_str()));

                            getline(ss, token,','); // <-- Token for Minute;
                                timeValue.setMinute(atoi(token.c_str()));

                            for(int i = 0; i<9; i++)
                                getline(ss, token, ',');

                            getline(ss, token,','); // <-- Token for WindSpeed
                                WS.setTime(timeValue);
                                WS.setWindspeed(atof(token.c_str()));

                            getline(ss,token,','); // <-- Token for Solar Radiation
                                SR.setTime(timeValue);
                                SR.setSolarRadiation(atof(token.c_str()));


                            wLog.insertDataSR(SR);
                            wLog.insertDataWS(WS);
                    }
                    else{
                            getline(ss, token,':'); // <-- Token for Hour;
                                timeValue.setHour(atoi(token.c_str()));

                            getline(ss, token,','); // <-- Token for Minute;
                                timeValue.setMinute(atoi(token.c_str()));

                            for(int i = 0; i<9; i++)
                                getline(ss, token, ',');

                            getline(ss, token,','); // <-- Token for WindSpeed
                                WS.setTime(timeValue);
                                WS.setWindspeed(atof(token.c_str()));

                            getline(ss,token,','); // <-- Token for Solar Radiation
                                SR.setTime(timeValue);
                                SR.setSolarRadiation(atof(token.c_str()));


                            wLog.insertDataSR(SR);
                            wLog.insertDataWS(WS);
                    }

                totalCount++;

                }
                cout << totalCount << endl;
                actualFile.close();
            }else
            return false;

        }

            myFile.close();
    }else
        return false;}
```

**Problem**
The problem is when the line reach end-of-file, it will end the loop immediatly but what i need is check if the current line is EOF, so it can enter the last month.

**edited :: Full Code

**edited :: thanks for you input guys, i just rewrite abit of my code, i change the loop param into `while(!actualFile.eof())` and for the if statement i put `if(day!=dayTemp || actualFile.eof())` and the getline is after the while loop

**Sorry for unclear question and title**

Comment: `getline` returns a value, perhaps think how it could be useful to you.

Comment: "it cant compare `if(MY!=atoi(MonthYear.c_str()))`" It isn't clear where the actual problem is. What do you mean when you say "cant compare"? Please **simplify** your code, remove irrelevant details and show (1) your input, (2) the desired result and (3) the actual result. Read about providing a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. thank you for helping but i re-write the code a bit and it works

Comment: @AndrewTruckle thanks for ur help i've read about those documentation but still didnt get but now everything good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:
Declare variable `bool reach;`

```
getline(file, line);
if(file.eof()) reach = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

I quote:

> The function will also stop extracting characters if the **end-of-file** is reached. If this is reached prematurely (before either writing n characters or finding delim), the function sets the **eofbit** flag.

More information here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/

You want to look at `rdstate`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/

And test for the flag `eofbit`.

That resource also shows you about `eof()`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/

It gives an example:

```
// ios::eof example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream is("example.txt");   // open file
  char c;
  while (is.get(c))                  // loop getting single characters
    std::cout << c;

  if (is.eof())                      // check for EOF
    std::cout << "[EoF reached]\n";
  else
    std::cout << "[error reading]\n";

  is.close();                        // close file
  return 0;
}
```

So, use `eof()` to test if you have reached the end of the file. But you can also do that flag test if approrpriate in your case. I think `eof()` is sufficient.

Comment: he wanted to know before reading the last line of the file whether next line of the file is the last line or not. For example if in a file there are 5 lines. Now while he is reading 4th line of the file he should know that next line would be the last line. Is there any possibility to know  before reading a line whether that line is last line of the file?

Comment: @Abhijit Obviously not. One should never assume a file follows a certain logic for the number of lines it in. If done efficiently you would move your line reading into a method and then you can do the needed tests and throw an exception. But his question specifically asks "how to know if next line is EOF". And you know by using the `eof()` call. It will return true the end of the file has been reached. If he meant "can I test if the next line is the last one in the file" then he should have worded it as such.